# Java-Abstract Classes

Tags: java

Consider the following class definition:

```
abstract class BaseOperation {
    protected int operandA;
    protected int operandB;
    public BaseOperation(int x, int y) {
        operandA = x;
        operandB = y;
    }
    public abstract int execute();
}
```

It has an abstract method. The abstract execute() method calculates an arithmetic operation and returns an integer value based on the type of the subclass. You are required to define the following:

- Define a subclass named AddOperation. The execute() method in the AddOperation class should add the two operands.
- Define a subclass named SubtractOperation. The execute() method in the SubtractOperation class should subtract the second operand from the first.
- Define a subclass named MultiplyOperation. The execute() method in the MultiplyOperation class should multiply the two operands.

For example:

**Test：**

```
AddOperation op = new AddOperation(8, 2);
System.out.println(op.execute());
if (!(op instanceof BaseOperation )) System.out.println("The AddOperation class must extends BaseOperation");
**RESULT：**
10
```

**TREST2：**

```
SubtractOperation op = new SubtractOperation(8, 2);
System.out.println(op.execute());
if (!(op instanceof BaseOperation )) System.out.println("The SubtractOperation class must extends BaseOperation");
**RESULT：**
6
```

Here is the code I attempted, Please have a look.

```
abstract class BaseOperation { 
    protected int operandA; 
    protected int operandB; 

    public BaseOperation(int x, int y) { 
        operandA = x; 
        operandB = y; 
    } 
    public abstract int execute(); 
} 
class AddOperation extends BaseOperation{ 
    public AddOperation(int x, int y){ 
        super(x, y); 
    } 
    public int execute(){ 
        return operandA + operandB; 
    }; 
} 
class SubtractOperation extends BaseOperation{ 
    public SubtractOperation(int x, int y){ 
        super(x, y); 
    } 
    public int execute(){ 
        return operandA - operandB; 
    }; 
} 
class MultiplyOperation extends BaseOperation{ 
    public MultiplyOperation(int x, int y){ 
        super(x, y); 
    } 
    public int execute(){ 
        return operandA * operandB; 
    }; 
}
```

And the error message, please help me to change it. Many thanks~

```
    Syntax Error(s)
__Tester__.java:11: error: duplicate class: BaseOperation
abstract class BaseOperation { 
         ^
1 error
```

Comment: You simply re-defined `BaseOperation`. Remove one.

Comment: You don't need to define `BaseOperation` again in your code. It's already there.

Answer (score 0):

You might be already having `BaseOperation.java` in the package and in the `Tester.java` you again redefined BaseOperation class, which is a duplicate.
Either 
a) Delete the duplicate BaseOperation code in Tester.java and import BaseOperation class.
b) Delete BaseOperation.java.